# Entity Framework database generation error

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

I'm making a model-first database and I'm trying to generate my MySql schema. When I click on "Generate Database from Model" it gives me this error

```
Encountered the following errors while processing the template 'E:\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Entity Framework Tools\DBGen\SSDLToMySQL.tt: 

Line 141, Column 0: 'Running transformation: System.NullReferenceException: Object     reference not set to an instance of an object.

   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplatingE384461094E1DFC8313DC1AA4CE547BEB91411CCECC4E940B2CAA4A167C5F68F403F4103FA7B7E1BB1B4B97B86595FBABCAF62EA3385ABAA9AF47E060E49D857.GeneratedTextTransformation.GetProviderManifestToken(String edmxPath) in e:\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Entity Framework Tools\DBGen\GenerateMySQL.Utility.ttinclude:line 142

   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplatingE384461094E1DFC8313DC1AA4CE547BEB91411CCECC4E940B2CAA4A167C5F68F403F4103FA7B7E1BB1B4B97B86595FBABCAF62EA3385ABAA9AF47E060E49D857.GeneratedTextTransformation.TransformText() in e:\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Entity Framework Tools\DBGen\SSDLToMySQL.tt:line 121'
```

I went and checked the references files and I'm not sure what I should do. Here are the files content at the targetted lines.

GenerateMySQL.Utility.ttinclude

```
(142 -->) foreach (var node in xmlDocument.SelectSingleNode("/edmx:Edmx/edmx:Runtime/edmx:StorageModels", namespaceMgr).ChildNodes)
{
  if (((XmlNode)node).Name.Equals("Schema") && ((XmlNode)node).Attributes.GetNamedItem("ProviderManifestToken") != null)
  {
      return ((XmlNode)node).Attributes["ProviderManifestToken"].Value;
  }
}
return String.Empty;
```

SSDLToMySQL.tt

```
EnvDTE.DTE env = (EnvDTE.DTE)((IServiceProvider)this.Host).GetService(typeof(EnvDTE.DTE));      
(121 -->)string serverVersion = GetProviderManifestToken(edmxPath);
string connection = String.Empty;
```

I know it used to work before but now it just gives me this error. It is an extremely simple schema, 3 tables with Strings and Int32's, some relationships. The project is otherwise empty and no modifications have been done other than the initial setup of the Mysql connection.

I have MySql Connector version 6.7.4 and Entity Framewiork v6.0.1 on Visual Studio 2012.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the problem by changing the SSDLToMySQL.tt at line 121 from

```
string serverVersion = GetProviderManifestToken(edmxPath);
```

to

```
string serverVersion = String.Empty;
```

Looks like it now finds the correct .edmx file.

Comment: I was having this exact same problem, your solution worked, you rock!

Answer (score 0):

I tried Tristan Dube's answer but ran into later issues.  I now appear to have a working configuration with EF6, mysql-connector-net-6.8.3, and mysql-visualstudio-plugin-1.1.1. The mysql-installer-community-5.6.15.0 didn't offer either of these, so I found them on a mirror of mysql.com:
ftp://gd.tuwien.ac.at/db/mysql/Downloads/Connector-Net/mysql-connector-net-6.8.3.msi
ftp://gd.tuwien.ac.at/db/mysql/Downloads/MySQLInstaller/mysql-visualstudio-plugin-1.1.1.msi